# Unable to install or run the application - System.Windows.Interactivity Version 4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, clickonce, mvvm-light

I am absolutely stuck.Searched and searched.
I have a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity Version 4.5.0.0
When I release the system via ClickOnce the system does not installed and reports the following error.

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires
>   that assembly System.Windows.Interactivity Version 4.0.0.0 be
>   installed in the global assembly cache (GAC) first.

I am using DevExpress tools along with MVVMLight. If I try and add version 4.0.0.0 I get errors as 4.5 is required. Any help would be gratefully accepted. Thanks Scott

Comment: I figured it out to be a reference with DevExpress. I have posted on their site and waiting response.

Answer (score 3):

When you publish your application - probably you have this in your output:
No way to resolve conflict between "System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, ....".

What you need to do is add remapping in app.config 
like it's done here [What should I change when the compiler tells me to "Consider app.config remapping" when I have no app.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164239/what-should-i-change-when-the-compiler-tells-me-to-consider-app-config-remappin)

Answer (score 2):

Consider remapping it in app.config like this:

```
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but a other Problem and i was able to solve it by Checking following List

- Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework
- Check the Target Framework of your `System.Windows.Interactivity`
- Check the Target Framework of your `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`

Answer (score 0):

In the Package Manager Console, run: `Install-Package Expression.Blend.Sdk`

Here is the package [Expression.Blend.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/) and contains both 4.0 and 4.5 versions of System.Windows.Interactivity